# How to center the container of a flexbox on top of a grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

From the below code, the navlinks and logo are centered within the header but I'm having issues with the flexbox container to be centered on top of the grid. As you can see, the cat image is slightly off-centered to the right.

I've tried hard coding margins but plan to make this page responsive so it wasn't efficient solution. I've also tried creating a container for my navigation links but it made no changes with centering with margin: 0 auto.

```
header
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: sticky;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nav
{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0%;
}


.navLink
{
    padding: 0 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2pdxqr05/3/

I expect the logo to be dead center between the red and blue column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav items were all different widths, Enjoy

This ensures the width of the nav items to be equal:

```
header > div{
    width:120px;
}
```

[View updated code here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hn2mytj)

```css
header
{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 position: sticky;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
}

body 
{
 max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 1000px
    padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;

}

.nav
{
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0%;
}


.navLink
{
 padding: 0 25px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;

}

header > div{
  width:120px;
}

#logo
{
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 //width: 4%;
 //height: 4%;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.container
{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr
}

.content 
{
 grid-column: content;
  background-color: red;

}

.images
{
 grid-column: images;
 text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div class = "nav">
  <header>
   <div class = "navLink" id="story-scroll">Our Story</div>
   <div class = "navLink" id="menu-scroll">Menu</div>
      <div class = "navLink">
     <img src = "https://placekitten.com/50/50" id="logo" lt="logo">
      </div>
   <div class = "navLink" id="press-scroll">Press</div>
   <div class = "navLink" id="contact-scroll">Contact</div>
  </header>
 </div>
  <div class = "container">

  <div class = "content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
   
  <div class = "images">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy solution. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your code like below. The trick is to handle free space distribution to be sure the image will stay in the center:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center; no more needed*/ 
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
header > div:nth-child(2),
header > div:nth-child(4){
  flex:1;
}
/*make the last and first one take more space*/
header > div:first-child,
header > div:last-child{
  flex:5;
}
/*align first and second to right*/
header > div:first-child,
header > div:nth-child(2) {
 text-align:right;
}


body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 1000px padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navLink {
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr
}

.content {
  grid-column: content;
  background-color: red;
}

.images {
  grid-column: images;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <header>
    <div class="navLink" id="story-scroll">Our Story</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="menu-scroll">Menu</div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" id="logo" lt="logo">
    <div class="navLink" id="press-scroll">Press</div>
    <div class="navLink" id="contact-scroll">Contact</div>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>

  <div class="images">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learned a lot about flexbox from it and plan to implement it!